# Content-Type of Rest Api returning Null in salesforce

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, visualforce

i am trying to call this rest api method

```
 @HttpGet
    global static String retrievingNotificationSettings(){

     RestRequest req=RestContext.request;

    RestResponse res=RestContext.response;

      String accountId = req.requestURI.substring(req.requestURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
     if(req.headers.get('Content-Type').equals('application/xml'))
     {
      Map<String, SObjectField> fields = Notification_Settings__c.SObjectType.getDescribe().fields.getMap();

      Schema.sObjectField T ;
      Notification_Settings__c ss;
      return 'hello World';

      }  


      if(req.headers.get('Content-Type').equals('application/json'))

    return System.JSON.serialize(note);


    return null;
```

My request is

```
GET /services/apexrest/v.9/notifications/preferences/ritesh HTTP/1.1
X-HostCommonName:
ap1.salesforce.com
Authorization:
OAuth 00D90000000j9AW!AQkAQLba73cDzjXhQ4kkQ2PSru4XpFuJcwr5kg_W_MkZmQnm9vI653FBWeJaABwClQqtJZD_b6j7V0O_elkzvkh7IqRKSUop
X-PrettyPrint:
1
Host:ap1.salesforce.com
X-Target-URI:
https://ap1.salesforce.com
Content-Type: application/json
Connection:Keep-Alive
```

and the response i am getting is

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Date:
Fri, 25 Jan 2013 16:30:21 GMT
Content-Length:
203
Connection:
close
Content-Type:
application/json; charset=UTF-8
Server:

[
   {
    "message": "System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object\n\nClass.NotificationRestService.retrievingNotificationSettings: line 34, column 1",
    "errorCode": "APEX_ERROR"
  }
]
```

the line where i am getting error is

if(req.headers.get('Content-Type').equals('application/xml'))

i didn't understand why i am getting this error when in header i am passing value Content-Type as application/json ?? please tell me where i am making mistake

Answer (score 0):

Can you `System.debug(req.headers)` to see if it was passed correctly?

To answer your null pointer question literally - use `==` instead of `equals`:

```
if(req.headers.get('Content-Type') == 'application/xml')
```

but that won't solve the real underlying problem.

You might want to try with different header (stupid, I know) or decide to add a GET parameter, something like `&mode=json`